# Shiny dateInput calendar on modal dialogue not move with page scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I gonna to get some information form users by a Shiny app. I use modal dialogue after clicking on a action botton. Date is one of these information which returns with shiny dateInput(). My problem is that the displayed calendar (after clicking on date text box) on modal dialogue, not move with page scrolling. Consider that I expected to collect several data from user and user should scroll down or up the page. In the cases where user use mobile phone the situation is worse. I provide a reproducible example and images. Thanks in advance for any recommendation.

ui:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  
    
  column(6,offset = 6,
         HTML('<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" style = "padding:10px">'),
         ### tags$head() This is to change the color of "Add a new row" button
         tags$head(tags$style(".butt2{background-color:#231651;} .butt2{color: #e6ebef;}")),
         div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = "Add_row_head",label = "Add", class="butt2") ),
         
         ### Optional: a html button 
         # HTML('<input type="submit" name="Add_row_head" value="Add">'),
         HTML('</div>') ),
  
  column(12,dataTableOutput("Main_table_trich")),
  tags$script("$(document).on('click', '#Main_table_trich button', function () {
                   Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
                   Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random()) });"),
  
  tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:#230682;} .butt{color: #e6ebef;}")), 
  
)
```

server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  vals_trich<-reactiveValues()
  vals_trich$Data<-data.frame(cnt_age=c(),
                              cnt_gender=c(),
                              cnt_date=c(),
                              cnt_h_size=c(),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$Add_row_head, {
    
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Add person", size="s" ,
                          shiny::div(id =("person"), 
                                     #tags$style(type = "text/css", ".datepicker { z-index: 99999 !important; }"),  
                                     shiny::wellPanel("panel", class = "myclass2", id = "myid2", 
                                                      sliderInput(paste0("cnt_age", input$Add_row_head),
                                                                  label = "Age" ,
                                                                  min = 0, max = 100, value = 0),
                                                      
                                                      
                                                      radioButtons(paste0("cnt_gender", input$Add_row_head),
                                                                   label = "Gender of reported contact",
                                                                   choices = structure(c("Female", "Male","Other"), .Names = c("Female", "Male","Other") ),
                                                                   selected = 99),
                                                      dateInput("cnt_date", "Date:", value = ""),
                                                 
                                                      sliderInput(paste0("cnt_h_size", input$Add_row_head),
                                                                  label = "Age of the contacted person" ,
                                                                  min = 0, max = 20, value = c(20))
                                              
                                                      
                                     )
                                     
                          ), 
                          
                          actionButton("go", "add item"),
                          easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL ),
             
              
    )
   
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    new_row=data.frame(
      cnt_age=input[[paste0("cnt_age", input$Add_row_head)]],
      cnt_gender=input[[paste0("cnt_gender", input$Add_row_head)]],
      cnt_date=input[["cnt_date"]],
      cnt_h_size=input[[paste0("cnt_h_size", input$Add_row_head)]]
       
    )
    vals_trich$Data<-rbind(vals_trich$Data,new_row )
    removeModal()
  })

 output$Main_table_trich<-renderDataTable({
    DT=vals_trich$Data
    datatable(DT,selection = "single",
              escape=F) })
  
}
```

[image: Before scrolling the page]
[image: After scrolling the page up]